# BST on c++ error

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

i tried to create BST on cpp
i done the class Node in the class Tree because it's logical.
header:

```
class Node;
class Tree
{
public:
    Node* root;
    Tree();
    Tree(int val);
    void insert(int val);
    class  Node
    {
    public:
        Node();
        Node(int val);
        Node* right;
        Node* left;
        int val;
    };

};
```

implamation:

```
Tree::Tree()
{
    this->root = NULL;

}
Tree::Node::Node()
{

}
Tree::Node::Node(int val)
{
    this->val = val;
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
}
void Tree::insert(int val)
{

    this->root = new Node(3);

}
```

i got an error on

```
this->root = new Node(3);


IntelliSense: a value of type "Tree::Node *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Node *"   
error C2440 : '=' : cannot convert from 'Tree::Node *' to 'Node *'
```

what did i done wrong please?
root this Node* 
and new Node (3) return Node*
what is the problem?
thanks!!!

Comment: Why are you forward-declaring `class Node;` ?

Comment: You've got 2 `class Node`s, one outside `class Tree` and one inside.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, in your current implementation, you are declaring two classes with the name `Node`; one is in the global scope while the other one is in the scope of the class `Tree`. This can be solved by using only one class.